# What is the relation between multiple regression and regression of residuals?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, residuals, nested-models

Suppose we have a multiple regression model:

```
data(iris)
mod <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Sepal.Length, data=iris)
```

We can see the "unique" contribution of `Sepal.Length` in predicting `Petal.Length`:

```
summary(mod)

             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  -1.50714    0.33696  -4.473 1.54e-05 ***
Petal.Width   1.74810    0.07533  23.205  < 2e-16 ***
Sepal.Length  0.54226    0.06934   7.820 9.41e-13 ***
```

In other words, we can see that Sepal.Length is associated with Petal.Length after "controlling" for Petal.Width.

Another approach to controlling for a variable is to regress with one predictor, and then regress on the residuals with a second predictor:

```
mod2 <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data=iris)
mod3 <- lm(residuals(mod2) ~ Sepal.Length, data=iris)

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  -1.04871    0.26527  -3.953 0.000119 ***
Sepal.Length  0.17947    0.04495   3.993 0.000103 ***
```

However the t-statistic and p-value are not the same. My understanding is that the latter leads to a biased estimate, but what exactly is the relationship between the t-statistic and p-value for `Sepal.Length` in `mod` compared to the corresponding statistics for `Sepal.Length` in `mod3`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to adjust for `Petal.Width` in both `Petal.Length` and `Sepal.Length`:

```
mod.y.adj <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data=iris)
mod.x.adj <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data=iris)

Petal.Length.adj <- mod.y.adj$residuals
Sepal.Length.adj <- mod.x.adj$residuals

mod.adj <- lm(Petal.Length.adj ~ Sepal.Length.adj, data=iris)
```

Now, the t statistic should be the same. I see from my output that they differ in the second decimal (7.8465 vs 7.8199). Note that the degrees of freedom is wrong in the adjusted model, because R is now unaware of `Petal.Width`. But you can easily calculate the p-value using `pt()` with the correct degrees of freedom.

Answer (score 2):

Notice the following:

$$-1.04871/0.26527 = -3.953
$$

$$0.17947/0.04495 = 3.993
$$

So the value divided by the standard error is the t-statistic.

In general, when we assume that $\beta=0$ (standard assumption):

$$\dfrac{\hat{\beta}-\beta}{SE(\hat{\beta})} \sim t
$$

Comment: Sorry I am having difficulty formulating my question. I understand how to calculate a t-statistic for a regression model. I am wondering how the t-statistic/p-value for `Sepal.Length` in `mod` relates to the corresponding statistics for `Sepal.Length` in `mod3`